# Powershell script giving an error but runs in shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a requirement to create and update a distribution list for a specific manager and 2 levels down of direct reports. I admit I am not a creative person so I used powershell and did it the best way I could think to do it. The problem is this will be scheduled to run every couple weeks to update the list so it needs to see if a user exists, if not then add him. in the "If" statement to do this I am running into errors when running the script, but if I pull the section of code out and just run manually in powershell it works.

My Execution policy is set to unrestricted so I do not think that is the issue.
We are running Powershell 2 and Unfortunately I can't change that.

Here is my script and the error I am getting.I realize two strings do not match in the lower part of the code, even though they both do the same thing to different files. If I ever get past errors in the first one I should be able to put the same code in both for it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $Identity="User"
 $Listname="Global-Leader"

#     This Script will work from a specified Manager and get his direct reports down 2 Levels then #add them to a specified list. This Script works in the AD Module. 
# ====================
#|        My Company
#| SCRIPT NAME: Leader
#| VERSION: 1
#| VERSION DATE: 3/24/2015
#| AUTHOR: Powershell Rookie
#====================
#load ActiveDirectory module If not already loaded.
if (!(Get-Module -Name ActiveDirectory)) {import-module ActiveDirectory}


Get-AdUser $Identity -properties DirectReports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports | Get-ADUser -Property * | Select SamAccountName, DisplayName, Office | Export-csv c:\work\leaders.csv

Import-Csv c:\work\Leaders.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-AdUser $_.SamAccountName -Property DirectReports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports | Get-Aduser -Property * | Select SamAccountName, DisplayName, Office} | Export-csv c:\work\leaders1.csv

Import-csv C:\work\leaders.csv | Foreach-Object If (!(Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName –properties MemberOf).MemberOf –like “$listname”) {Add-ADGroupMember $listname –member $_.samAccountName}

Import-csv C:\work\leaders1.csv | Foreach-Object If ((Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName –properties MemberOf).MemberOf –like “$listname”) {Add-ADGroupMember $listname –member $_.samAccountName}

                if ((Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf).memberOf -like "$listName") {
                               Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$user is already a member of $listName"
                              } else {
                               Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Adding $user to $listName"
                               Add-ADGroupMember $ListName -member $user
                                }
```

And here is the error I keep getting:

```
[PS] C:\work>.\leader.ps1
Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement.
At C:\work\leader.ps1:25 char:143
+ Import-csv C:\work\leaders.csv | Foreach-Object If (!(Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName â?"properties MemberOf).MemberOf â?"like â?o$listnameâ
??) { <<<< Add-ADGroupMember $listname â?"member $_.samAccountName}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ({:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Looks like PowerShell does not detect UTF-8 if file does not have BOM, so save your files as UTF-8 with BOM, or eliminate not ASCII characters, for example: `–“”`.

Comment: Not related to the code issues, but if you are using Exchange, consider making custom dynamic distribution groups instead. No need to re-run scripts over and over if the group is setup right.

Comment: Is this the exact contents of the file? Because line 25 doesn't have a char 143 or a { in it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer when using -like you need to be less specific with your criteria.

`-like "*$Listname*"`

Like is looking for that specific text at the beginning of the item to be 
searched.  If that item can appear anywhere in the memberof then you need to either add the wildcards or use -match instead.  -match implies * around your search item.

Since most responses from that command should start with

`CN=`

Your member group will not be the first thing it finds

Hope that helps

[Difference between -like and -match](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_like.htm)